# New Payment Method in New Configuration Tab in Magento

Tags: php, magento, module, tabs, payment

All I want to do is to add a new custom payment method and make it available in a new configuration tab, instead of "Sales/Payment Methods".

For example I want to have my payment method under "CompanyName/Method1" in admin configuration instead of having a group under "Sales/Payment Methods".

My problem arises here. I can set up the system.xml file to have a new tab and my module options under it. But when I change config.xml, my payment method does not show up in the chekout page anymore.

When I change  to my custom tab name, it fails to show up in checkout. Any ideas?

```
<default>
        <payment>
            <spos>
                <active>0</active>
                <model>spos/payment</model>
                <order_status>1</order_status>
                <title>SPos</title>
                <payment_action>authorize</payment_action>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
            </spos>
        </payment>
</default>
```

Comment: why would you want to have a payment method not present in the payment methods tab?

Comment: because it will have many other sub methods inside it. So it should be better to have a seperate tab for this method

Answer (score 0):

http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration

This like will helps you.

Comment: thank you for the link. But I need something more focused on payment methods. I have followed the instructions in the link you provided but when it comes to implementing for my payment method, it does not show up in the checkout.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to show your config.xml and system.xml. I have tried for this and my xmls are as follows:

System.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <newmodule translate="label" module="newmodule">
            <label>NewModule</label>
            <sort_order>200</sort_order>
        </newmodule>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <newmodule translate="label" module="newmodule">
            <label>NewModule</label>
            <tab>newmodule</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <newmodule translate="label" module="paygate">
                    <label>NewModule Payment</label>
                    <sort_order>670</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <active translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>  
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </active>
                        <order_status translate="label">
                            <label>New order status</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_order_status_processing</source_model>
                            <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </order_status>
                        <title translate="label">
                            <label>Title</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </title>
                    </fields>
                </newmodule>
            </groups>
        </newmodule>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <NameSpace_NewModule>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </NameSpace_NewModule>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <newmodule>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>NameSpace_NewModule</module>
                    <frontName>newmodule</frontName>
                </args>
            </newmodule>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <newmodule>
                    <file>newmodule.xml</file>
                </newmodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <newmodule>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>NameSpace_NewModule</module>
                    <frontName>newmodule</frontName>
                </args>
            </newmodule>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <newmodule module="newmodule">
                <title>NewModule</title>
                <sort_order>71</sort_order>
                <action>newmodule/adminhtml_newmodule</action>
                <children>
                    <marketing module="newmodule">
                        <title>Marketing</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>newmodule/adminhtml_newmodule</action>
                    </marketing>                    
                </children>
            </newmodule>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <newmodule>
                            <title>NewModule</title>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <action>newmodule/adminhtml_newmodule</action>
                            <children>
                            <marketing module="newmodule">
                                <title>Marketing</title>
                                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                                <action>newmodule/adminhtml_newmodule</action>
                            </marketing>                           
                            </children>
                        </newmodule>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <newmodule>
                    <file>newmodule.xml</file>
                </newmodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <global>
        <fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote_payment>
                <newmodule_id>
                    <to_order_payment>*</to_order_payment>
                </newmodule_id>               
                <order_cash_value>
                    <to_order_payment>*</to_order_payment>
                </order_cash_value>
            </sales_convert_quote_payment>
            <sales_convert_order_payment>
                <budget_id>
                    <to_quote_payment>*</to_quote_payment>
                </budget_id>                
                <order_cash_value>
                    <to_quote_payment>*</to_quote_payment>
                </order_cash_value>
            </sales_convert_order_payment>
        </fieldsets>
        <models>
            <newmodule>
                <class>NameSpace_NewModule_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>newmodule_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </newmodule>
            <newmodule_mysql4>
                <class>NameSpace_NewModule_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <newmodule>
                        <table>newmodule</table>
                    </newmodule>                    
                </entities>
            </newmodule_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <newmodule_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>NameSpace_NewModule</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </newmodule_setup>
            <newmodule_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </newmodule_write>
            <newmodule_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </newmodule_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <newmodule>
                <class>NameSpace_NewModule_Block</class>
            </newmodule>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <newmodule>
                <class>NameSpace_NewModule_Helper</class>
            </newmodule>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <default>
        <payment>
            <newmodule>
                <active>1</active>
                <model>newmodule/payment_newmodule</model>
                <order_status>processing</order_status>
                <title>NewModule Payment</title>
                <payment_action>authorize</payment_action>
            </newmodule>
        </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

Hope this may help you. Check these xmls and compare it..

Answer (score 0):

You must add `<config_path>payment/[YourGroupName]/[FieldName]</config_path>` node to each new payment's field which is under your new group section.
So your fields are something look like this in your system.xml file:

```
...
    <fields>
        <active translate="label">
            <label>Enabled</label>
            <config_path>payment/method1/active</config_path>
            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
        </active>
        <title translate="label">
            <label>Title</label>
            <config_path>payment/method1/title</config_path>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>15</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
        </title>
        .
        .
        .
    </fields>
...
```

PayPal module in Magento is a vary good reference to check, learn and find new things for payment methods.